# Low latency short range high resolution visible light laser proximity sensor unit

Tags: sensor, laser

I'm a software developer looking into using sensors as input devices for novel musical instruments, currently a laser proximity sensor. I would like to ask for help finding a suitable unit. The need-to-have requirements are:

- Real time operation: I require a continuous stream of data rather than triggered discreet events.
- High spacial resolution: 0.01mm - 0.001mm, the more the better
- High time resolution: If this is a digital unit at least 1000Hz, the more the better
- Medium range: 500mm-1500mm (enough for a standing performer to trigger it by hand)
- Medium cost: Cheaper is better of course, but a couple hundred dollars would be okay
- The output should end up in a linux computer as some kind of data stream (C SDK, linux named pipe, OSC). The device could have analog output to be combined with a DSP, or be connected digitally.
- The device should be a finished unit that does not require hardware development, like adjusting triangulation angles or debugging visual artefacts, but basics like connecting cables, mounting or soldering are fine.
- Change of distance over time is more important than absolute distance
- The device should be triggerable by hand (colored gloves would be acceptable)
- Visible light laser (for the show effect, but mostly for better visual control)
- Low latency: The data stream in the computer should be delayed from the physical movement by no more than 10ms, preferably less than 3ms.

My previous attempts include trying to build a laser triangulator from an analog linear sensor and a green laser, but I would prefer not to invest more time in building the necessary hardware development skills to do it right.

I also tried a [sharp infrared unit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8958), but the resolution was too low (1024 steps in 1m makes for 1mm resolution, not enough to express musical subtleties). The sharp was the closest finished unit I could find so far.

Researching this list, I also heard the term interferometer, which sounded like it had attractive properties.

What kind of units could I use? How would I go about finding them? Google seems to yield mostly cheaper units geared at home robotics. I am guessing I would need something created with industrial use in mind.

Comment: Sounds like a phase shift distance sensor could be your best best. Not sure about existing commercial products. However, I have been mulling over a couple of different designs for a unit with a range of 0 to 3m, khz update rate, and sub mm resolution. No prototypes yet, but I would be open to discuss.

Comment: Also, how many channels do you need? Just one, or several?

Comment: can't use capacitive proximity sensors?

Comment: @alex.forencich The planned devices you describe sound like a great fit. I had two seperate one-channel devices in mind.

Comment: @Jasen My difficulty is in finding one that satisfies the criteria above.

Comment: what about hacking a Kinect (tm)?

Comment: @user44635 I assumed the latency would be more than 20ms for a kinect. Looking more for something COTS already built at scale for industrial applications that I can repurpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to severely rethink your requirements. You appear to be trying for a laser-based Theremin. A few objections then arise.

1) Millisecond response time. People cannot move their hands with millisecond control. Basic human reaction time is on the order of a tenth of a second or two.

2) Spatial resolution. .001 mm. Are you kidding? That is 40 millionths of an inch! I defy you to control your hand to that sort of accuracy. Any system which will produce detectible results for that kind of motion will be wildly uncontrollable.

3) Visible light laser. (for the show effect, but mostly for better visual control) Are you making a light show or an instrument? You do understand, I hope, that an instrument is judged on the sounds it makes, rather than visual effects. Visual feedback in an acoustic device invites feedback conflict.

Comment: This would more appropriately be a comment.

Comment: (1) Yes they can, it's called professional training. Reaction time is irrelevant, notes are pre-planned in the brain before they are played. What matters is lag; more than 10ms is unplayable for rhythmic purposes, and sound generation already takes at least 3ms.

Comment: (2) 0.001 may be excessive, but 0.01 probably is not. To capture the correct "feel" of an acoustic instrument for an electronic instrument, involuntary movement is important too. And that will be very, very subtle; again, we are talking trained professionals here. Any less than that and you giving a fisher price fiddle to Yehudi Menuhin.

Comment: (3) I want to create an instrument that works and that is also showy. This is crucial; this is for a live show, not an academic exercise in purity.

Comment: All in all: I understand that these requirements may be hard implement; that would explain why there are no laser theremins commercially available now. But from the usability perspective, with the possible exception of 0.001mm, they stand as they are.